# Getting undesired output in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm new beginner to SQL. I want to list all the codes and names of all subject. In the case of those subjects, for which any of the students registered for the first time, listing the recommended exam date(s) as well.

Order of columns of the result set:

```
neptuncode, subjectname, examdate
```

I ran the following query

```
SELECT 
    subjects.neptuncode AS "neptuncode",
    subjects.subjectname AS "subjectname", 
    enrollments.examdate AS "examdate"
FROM 
    subjects
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    enrollments ON enrollments.subject = subjects.subject_ID 
GROUP BY 
    subjects.neptuncode, subjects.subjectname, enrollments.examdate
HAVING 
    COUNT(enrollments.enrollmentdate) = 1
ORDER BY  
    subjects.neptuncode, subjects.subjectname, enrollments.examdate;
```

The result is only subjects which registered by students for the first time alongside neptuncode and examdate. I would like to list also all subjects with their neptuncode and examdate (it should be NULL because only the subjects which are registered for the first time have exam date value in the column). But I am stuck at doing this. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  So would an appropriate database tag.

Comment: If you remove the HAVING clause, does that result look better?

Comment: When removing HAVING clause it gives all the exam dates with all subjects. I need exam dates with the subjects which is registered for the first time by any students

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you try this please

```
SELECT
     subjects.neptuncode AS "neptuncode"
   , subjects.subjectname AS "subjectname"
   , CASE WHEN COUNT(enrollments.enrollmentdate) = 1 THEN MAX(enrollments.enrollmentdate)
          ELSE NULL
     END AS "examdate"
FROM subjects
LEFT OUTER JOIN enrollments
    ON enrollments.subject = subjects.subject_ID
GROUP BY
     subjects.neptuncode
   , subjects.subjectname
ORDER BY
     subjects.neptuncode
   , subjects.subjectname
;
```

I believe you need to treat the `enrollmentdate` as an aggregate, as only 1 enrollment date is permitted you can use either `max()` or `min()`.

Comment: It did not give the all subjects which is in the database

Comment: Please re-try, I altered the query more than once (sorry). But it will not give ALL subjects - **unless the count of enrollments is <= 1**. If this query does not work then I suggest that trying to describe (in words) what you expect isn't working. Provide **sample data** and the **expected result** (as tables, not as words). Use fixed format text tables, not images, this url may help: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: I want to list all subject name and codes from database. In the case of those subjects for which any of the students registered for the first time, list exam date for this condition. In other words result is all subjects with subjectname, neptuncode and examdate. If above mentioned condition is true write the examdate in the colum otherwise leave as null for the rest which is not registered for the first time

Comment: In your mind you have an image of that expected result. The design of that result is well formed because you already know the data, you have seen it many times, plus you control the requirements as well. I know only the few words you have used; in 3 places (the question, and a comment under the question, and the comment just above) and in all those places there are different words/variations of that explanation. This is why words are not a great way to DEFINE the **expected result** - data is the best way.

Comment: In response to your latest description I have removed the `having clause` and introduced a `case expression`. I probably will not attempt another query variant based on description of the result wanted.

Comment: That is what I wanted. Thanks a lot appreciate your efforts.